# Parallel way of filtering no more than 1 point in a neighbourhood

Tags: python, geometry, mpi

I have a space of `23x23x30` and each cube of `1x1x1` represents a point, some of these `23x23x30` points are populated with numbers ranging from `-65 to -45`, I want to make sure that there should be no more than 1 number in any given region of `5x5x30` around a populated point, if there are multiple points in any region of `5x5x30` the points with the smallest number should be eliminated. I have done this in serial way using nested `for` loops but that's very expensive operation. I would like to parallelize this operation. I have `n` cores and each core has it's own sub region of the total region of `23x23x30` without any overlap. I can collect those 'sub regions' and construct the full region of `23x23x30` that was mentioned above, so that all cores can access full region of `23x23x30` at the same time they have their 'sub region' as well. I am not sure if there are any libraries available for this kind of operation in python. In my application 8 processes will fill up this `23x23x30` space with about `3500` points, rite now I'm doing this 'filtering' operation on all the 8 processes(i.e duplicating the work) this is wastage of resources, so I will have to do this 'filtering' in parallel in order to use the available resource efficiently.

Here is the serial code: `self.tntatv_stdp_ids` is a dictionary with keys `step1`, `step2`....upto `30` steps in dimension, `z`. This keys have the numbers(`1 to 529`) of the points in that step that are populated. Note that in serial implementation of the code, points in each step in the `z` dimension are from `1 to 529`.

`self.cell_voltages`  is a dictionary with keys `step1`, `step2`....upto `30` steps in dimension, `z`. Each key gives the numbers that present in a point.

```
     a_keys = self.tntatv_stdp_ids.keys()

    #Filter tentative neuron ids using suppression algo to come up with final stdp neuron ids. 
    for i in range(0,len(a_keys)):
        b_keys= list(set(a_keys) - set([a_keys[i]]))
        c_keys = self.tntatv_stdp_ids[a_keys[i]]

        for j in range(0,len(b_keys)):
            d_keys=self.tntatv_stdp_ids[b_keys[j]]
            for k in c_keys[:]:
                key = k 
                key_row= key/(image_size-kernel+1)
                key_col = key%(image_size-kernel+1)
                remove =0
                for l in d_keys[:]:
                    target = l 
                    tar_row = target/(image_size-kernel+1)
                    tar_col = target%(image_size-kernel+1)

                    if(abs(key_row-tar_row) > kernel-1 and abs(key_col-tar_col) > kernel-1):
                        pass
                    else:
                        if(self.cell_voltages[a_keys[i]][key]>=self.cell_voltages[b_keys[j]][target]):
                            d_keys.remove(target)
                        else:
                            remove+=1
                if(remove):
                    c_keys.remove(key)
```

At the end of this operation , if there are multiple points left over in  `30` regions of `23x23x1`, one final winner point for each of those `30` `23x23x1` regions can be selected by seeing which of the remaining populated points of`23x23x1` points has the highest number. In this way the maximum number of winners can be `30` from all of the points in `23x23x30`, 1 for each of the `23x23x1`. There can be less than `30` also, depends upon how many of the `23x23x30` points were populated to start with.

Comment: of the ~8.4m cells, how many are populated?

Comment: Varies but not more than 3500 cells.

Comment: Your question would benefit from a [mcve]: [Edit] your question to include what you've tried so far.

Comment: I havn't tried it in parallel yet, I will use MPI, I am looking for other python packages which will prevent reinventing the wheel.

Comment: This problem is unlikely to require a parallel solution. It can be solved in less than a minute on a normal computer. Your approach is likely flawed, not your framework.

Comment: I can generate a 529x529x30 grid, fill it with 3500 random nodes and then prune those nodes as you described in ~3 seconds, most of which is the time to build the starting array. Please [edit] your question to include what you've tried.

Comment: I have edited the question, it's 23x23x30 sorry for the mistake, a minute is too much time, I am trying to speedup compared to serial operation.

Comment: 23x23x30 only has ~16k nodes, of which 3.5k are filled? And you want to remove all but one in each 5x5 (750 block) chunk?

Comment: In any of the 5x5x30 region, there should be no more than one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem doesn't likely require parallelization:

```
# Generate a random array of appropriate size for testing
super_array = [[[None for _ in range(30)] for _ in range(529)] for _ in range(529)]
for _ in range(3500):
    super_array[random.randint(0, 528)][random.randint(0, 528)][random.randint(0,29)] = random.randint(-65, -45)
```

First step is building a list of filled nodes:

```
filled = []
for x in range(len(super_array)):
    for y in range(len(super_array[0])):
        for z in range(len(super_array[0][0])):
            if super_array[x][y][z] is not None:
                filled.append((x, y, z, super_array[x][y][z]))
```

Then, sort list from high to low:

```
sfill = sorted(filled, key=lambda x: x[3], reverse=True)
```

Now, generate a blocking grid:

```
block_array = [[None for _ in range(529)] for _ in range(529)]
```

And traverse the list, blocking off neighborhoods as you find nodes and deleting nodes in an already occupied neighborhood:

```
for node in sfill: 
    x, y, z, _ = node
    if block_array[x][y] is not None:
        super_array[x][y][z] = None  # kill node if it's in the neighborhood of a larger node
    else: # Block their neighborhood
        for dx in range(5):
            for dy in range(5):
                cx = x + dx - 2
                cy = y + dy - 2
                if 529 > cx >= 0 and 529 > cy >= 0:
                    block_array[cx][cy] = True
```

Some notes:

- This uses a sliding neighborhood, so it checks a 5x5 centered on each node. Doing the check from highest to lowest is important, as that ensures a node which is removed hasn't previously forced a different node to be removed.
- You could do this even more efficiently by doing ranges instead of a full 529x529 array, but the neighborhood blocking takes less than a second and the full process, from generated array to pruned final list is 1.2 seconds.
- Building of a filled nodes list could be improved by only adding the highest value node within any `z` stack. This will reduce the size of the list which must be sorted if a significant number of nodes end up with the same x,y values.

On a 23x23x30, it takes about ~18ms, again including the time to build the 3d array:

```
timeit.timeit(prune_test, number=1000)
17.61786985397339
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this(i'm a new comer). I will have to use parallel here because my 8 processes will fill the 23x23x30 space with about 3500 points, I can make all the processes do the same work but that's waste of resources, instead I am looking for a way to parallelize this. Your serial solution is better than mine.

Comment: ["... about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil."](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092/253386) Unless you've profiled it and know that's what is slowing down your program, it likely isn't worth optimizing. Splitting that 8 ways, even if you say the parallelization adds no overhead (spoiler: it does), it will save you what, 15ms per run? Is that significant in any way compared to the rest of the code required to complete a cycle of your program?